# NSUserNotification size OS X

Tags: macos, size, nsusernotification

I have this code that allows me to display notifications.

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
notification.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",titre, numero];
notification.informativeText = message;
notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.responsePlaceholder = @"Reply";
notification.hasReplyButton = true;
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
```

I saw that text, too large, is truncated. Is it possible to prevent this?

I also added the ability to reply to the notification. The text box displays only one line. Is it also possible to increase the size (height) of the area?

Or better, it is possible to increase the size (height) of a notification for it to fit more text or an larger text box ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I don't think it's possible to resize anything in a NSUserNotification, at least on 10.9.

Comment: I want to use bold font in notification... :(